# Dynamic UI Layout in DataGridCell using ItemsControl and a Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

[image]

This screenshot is from the mockup of my ideal UI. Right now, this is a *DataGridTemplateColumn*, with header = "ATTENDEES". I am running into issues creating the layout of this *DataGridColumn's* cell.

I currently have an *ItemsControl* bound to a *List* of strings which are the attendees' emails. If there are too many attendees and the *ItemsControls*' bounds cannot fit in the cell, then a *Button* with Content = "See more" should appear at the bottom of the cell, under the last attendee email that can be rendered within in the cell's bounds.

Then once the *Button* ("See more") is clicked, the row should expand to an appropriate height for the attendees to all be visible, and the "See more" *Button* should disappear.

I could not wrap my head around a clean implementation with a *TemplateSelector*, *ValueConverter*, or *DataTrigger* in pure XAML since I need to compare the *ItemsControls*' height against the *DataGridRow's* height and then perform a modification of the cell's layout at runtime by hiding all the items in the *ItemsControl* that cannot fit within the cell and then showing at *Button* below it.

I concluded on attempting to do this in the code-behind by subscribing to the *ItemControls*' load event. I first attempted to use the Height, MaxHeight, DesiredSize.Height, RenderedSize.Height, and ActualSize.Height properties of the ItemsControl but those all were equal to the clipped height of the ItemsControl, not the intrinsic height of all its contents.

I am now measuring the total height of all its items' strings using the *FormattedText* class. Then I compare this summed height with the row's height and that's as far as I have progressed; I am unsure of how to next change the layout of the cell or if this is even the correct approach.

I feel like I am fighting against the design of the WPF framework by doing rudimentary calculations and crude layout changes to the view in the code-behind.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here is my event handler for the ItemsControl.Load:

```
 private void AttendeesItemsControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentRowIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        List<ModelBase> eventsData = ModelManager.events.data;
        var eventObj = (Event)eventsData[currentRowIndex];
        var attendees = eventObj.attendees;
        var totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < attendees.Count; i++)
        {
            totalItemsHeight += heightOfString(attendees[i]);
        }
        var itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;
        var controlRenderHeight = itemsControl.RenderSize.Height;
        // Check if the intrinsic height is greater than what can be drawn inside the cell
        if (controlRenderHeight < totalItemsHeight)
        {
            var itemHeight = totalItemsHeight / attendees.Count;
            var visibleItemsCount = controlRenderHeight / itemHeight;
            // .... not sure how to proceed
        }
    }
```

And the helper function that measures the height of one of its items:

```
private int heightOfString(string candidate)
    {
        var fontFamily = new FontFamily("Lato");
        var fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
        var fontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        var fontStretch = FontStretches.Normal;
        var fontSize = 12;
        var typeFace = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(candidate, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeFace, fontSize, Brushes.Black);

        return (int)formattedText.Height;
    }
```

Finally, this is the DataGridTemplateColumn's XAML, with the cell template definition:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ATTENDEES" Width="*">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=attendees}" x:Name="AttendeesItemsControl" Loaded="AttendeesItemsControl_Loaded">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Lato" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>    
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Trying to work it out in my head, are you using a view model or just binding your list directly to your control? I think you could have a full contact list and a displayed contract list. When it originally loads it only adds the first 2. When they click the show more it pushes the rest of the list to the display list.

Comment: Back when I originally posted this question I was binding directly to a property of the control, declared in the code-behind, but now I have a view-model set as the data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some real work but I got this set up. Hopefully you can follow it. Here is a screen shot of what it looks like. Obviously i didn't attempt to style it yet. Just getting the resizing. This way you let WPF handle the height of your control you leave it autosized. You just manage your list.

[image: Demo Picture]

I created a control for the list called AttendeeListControl

```html
<UserControl xmlns:stackoverflow="clr-namespace:stackoverflow"  x:Class="stackoverflow.AttendeeListControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    
    <Grid Background="GhostWhite">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="37"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="23"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Attendees" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox Name="listBoxAttendees" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Content="SeeMore" Name="lblMore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="lblMore_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the code behind

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AttendeeListControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public partial class AttendeeListControl : UserControl
    {
        public AttendeeListViewModel vm { get; set; }
        public AttendeeListControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var emails = new List<string>() { "email@gmail.com", "email@aol.com", "email.yahoo.com", "email@msn.com" };
            var displayed = new ObservableCollection<string>() { emails[0], emails[1] };
            vm = new AttendeeListViewModel()
             {
                 EmailList = emails,
                 DisplayList = displayed,
                 Expanded = false
             };


            DataContext = vm;
            listBoxAttendees.ItemsSource = vm.DisplayList;

        }

        private void lblMore_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (vm.Expanded)
            {
                //remove all but last 2
                do
                {
                    vm.DisplayList.RemoveAt(vm.DisplayList.Count - 1);
                } while (vm.DisplayList.Count > 2);

                lblMore.Content = "Show More";
            }
            else
            {
                //don't want the first 2
                for (int i = 2; i < vm.EmailList.Count; i++)
                {
                    vm.DisplayList.Add(vm.EmailList[i]);
                }
                lblMore.Content = "Show Less";
            }

            vm.Expanded = !vm.Expanded;

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the model i used

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    public class AttendeeListViewModel
    {
        public bool Expanded { get; set; }

        public List<string> EmailList { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> DisplayList { get; set; }

    }
}
```

this was all just put on the mainwindow

```html
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stackoverflow" x:Class="stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <local:AttendeeListControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <local:AttendeeListControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and sorry for such a long delay. In your constructor of AttendeeListControl you set "displayed" to an ObservableCollection of 2 strings. The problem with this is that I need to dynamically calculate how many will be displayed based on the height of the AttendeeListControl's parent, which in my case, is a DataGridRow.

Comment: After thinking about this more and getting help from someone on Reddit, since the DataGridRow's height is static, let's say 45 points tall, we could just display only what can be shown in 45 points and then we can use some of your button clicking logic to show the rest!